# Dynamic sound file with .play()

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

Code I am creating is a function which with the function it should .play() it... here is the code

```
function playSound() {
document.getElementById('newMessage').play();
}

var sound = document.createElement('audio');
 sound.setAttribute("src","http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-2.wav");
 sound.id="newMessage";
 sound.setAttribute('autoplay','false');
 document.body.appendChild(sound);
```

Though everytime in console trying to do `playSound();` it says playSound is undefined. So then I try doing `document.getElementById('newMessage').play();` and it doesn't play either, nor does $('#newMessage').play(); which comes with an error of object [object Object] has no method play.

Any suggestions as this is the first time trying to dynamically create the audio file and use a function to play it. I've looked at a few other SO topics and well they don't seem to be leading me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: The reason it doesn't work with jQuery is because jQuery doesn't have a `play` method. If you wanted to select the element with jQuery, you'd have to use `$('#newMessage')[0].play();` or possibly `$('#newMessage').trigger("play");`

Comment: Thanks Ian for that reasoning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you're defining the `playSound` method after the page has already loaded, maybe in some `onload` method. If this is the case, try attaching the method to the `window` object:

```
window.playSound = function() {
  document.getElementById('newMessage').play();
}
```

This is make the function available even if the function is defined after the page loads. Also you shouldn't set autoplay to false. It defaults to false, and if you want to set it to true you set `autoplay="autoplay"`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GUqy/1/)

Comment: Good point, but it's still weird that `document.getElementById('newMessage').play();` doesn't "work" either

Comment: @Ian - Not sure what's wrong without a more complete code example. I just added a JSFiddle to my answer that shows a working example.

Comment: Of course, I think it's great that you show it's working. I'm just saying, it's weird that explicitly calling `.play()` on the element doesn't work for the OP. Your point about it not being available in the global scope could easily be the problem, but not being able to call `.play()` is the weird part

Comment: Yeah I'm not trying to get it for the onload. Except for when a new message "appears" it will have this in the PHP/JS for the new messages. playSound(); and it will play a sound. Unless the above would work like that within a function? Not sure. I'll have to take a look later at this script.

Comment: Ok I checked your code,in the fiddle, and I understand it a bit better. will this work outside the onclick="" event? I'd rather do this at the end of a code something like this---

$(Function() {
//code here 
//code here
playSound();
});

Comment: @EasyBB - Of course, you can call the playSound function from anywhere in your code.